# Failed to bounce to type with FirebaseListadAdpter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am working on Android Chat project and I have a ListView, which I want the messeges to populate through Firebase list adapter. Now after I run the code the app is crashing.

I try several ways to solve it with no success.
Does my conception is wrong and i should use a different method?
Anyway-

The exception is:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.example.giat.myapplication.ChatMessage] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method
```

This is the main code in MainActivity.java:

```
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://chat-as31da.firebaseio.com");

    Button sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText MessageTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
 sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String text =MessageTxt.getText().toString();
            ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage("Android User", text);
            mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(message);
            MessageTxt.setText("");

        }
    });

    final ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this,ChatMessage.class,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,mFirebaseRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.get_name());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.get_messag());
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);


}
```

And this is the POJO:

```
public class ChatMessage {

private String _name;
private String _message;

public ChatMessage() {}

public ChatMessage(String _name,String _message ) {
    this._name = _name;
    this._message = _message;
 }

public String get_name() {
    return _name;
 }

public String get_message() {
    return _message;
  }
}
```

JASON Snippet of data:

```
{
"_message" : "hi there",
"_name" : "sam"
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the JSON (as text please, no images) at `mFirebaseRef`?

Comment: I added the snippet of the JSON and edit the connection at  MainActivity.java.
Thank you for helping! :)

Comment: I think the names starting with an underscore may be causing problems for Jackson here. Try this simplest of possible classes: `public class ChatMessage { public String _name; public String _message; }` (so without getters/setters).

Comment: I deleted the underscore in the members:_name and _message so now I have this exception:

 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "_name" (class com.example.giat.myapplication.ChatMessage), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "messag", "name"])

Comment: I just notice its sending the old values now:

'
"-KOKvoarUcjyrz71L88q" : {
    "_messag" : "gi",
    "_name" : "Android User",
    "messag" : "gi",
    "name" : "Android User"
  }
'

Comment: Did you try the minimal class I provided? It still has the underscores (otherwise the code won't match your existing JSON data), but removes the getters/setters.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand how the app can work without getters/setters? so how can I display messeges in listView? Do you want me to add this class in MainActivity.Java? 
Sorry for my noob questions

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So I add the class you provided to my MainActivity.Java as static class and now everything is local (In the class) and it's work like a charm! TY!
BUT why it's not possible to do it with warps class as JavaBin? e.g. why the old fields are **still** save in Firebase db as addition to the new ones and how can I remove them from json (without using '@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)') ?

Comment: As I said, I think the underscore in `get_message` may be confusing Jackson. If that is the case, one solution would be to not use `_` prefixes in your JSON property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I found that I need to connect to Firebase database like this:

```
        mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<stack-overflow>.firebaseio.com/mychat");
```

Second, to solve the Jackson problem (names starting with underscore), with the help of @Frank van Puffelen I found that I need to make `ChatMessage` class as static in MainActivity and delete the setters/getters.

*Or*

I can just add `@JsonProperty` before my variables declaration and the getters in `ChatMessage` class.